# In C# how to get minimum and maximum value of char printed in Unicode format?

Tags: c#, unicode, char

According to MSDN the minimum value of char is U+0000 and maximum value of char is U+ffff

I have written the following code to print the same:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace myApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            char min = char.MinValue;
            char max = char.MaxValue;
            Console.WriteLine($"The range of char is {min} to {max}");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the output in the format U+0000 and U+ffff.

How to get it?

Comment: You want to print those as integers in hex.

Comment: Yes in hex but preceded with U+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `char` when formatted into a string is already represented as the character. I mean the `char` with value `0x30` is represented as `0`, not as `48`.

So you need to cast those values as `int` and display them hexadecimal (using the format specifier `X`):

```
int min = char.MinValue; // int - not char
int max = char.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine($"The range of char is U+{min:x4} to U+{max:x4}");
```

to see their numerical (hexadecimal) value.

Result:

```
The range of char is U+0000 to U+ffff
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: It is giving me desired output but is it possible to get output as U+0000 without using U+{min}?

Comment: @puregeek no, I don't think so. There is (afaik) no built-in way to say "print this char as it's unicode value"

Comment: If I give input in the form of unicode value such as U+0000 is it possible for C# to recognize as char or do I have to give it as 0000?

Comment: Instead of `int` one can also write `ushort` if preferred. In fact, `char` and `ushort` have the same range (unsigned 16-bit integer).